# Swift animation not sticking

Tags: ios, ipad, swift

I have a button when clicked I move an imageView with animation to another location on the screen with the following code:

```
@IBOutlet var CurrentPlayerTotal: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Player1: UIImageView!

UIImageView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
   self.Player1.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 178, width: 250, height: 350)
})
```

The image moves fine.

I have another button that updates a label on the screen.

```
@IBAction func Sub1(sender: AnyObject) {
    currentTotal -= 1
    CurrentPlayerTotal.text = "\(currentTotal )"
}
```

When I click this button the image returns to the original location. Why is this happening?

Here is a more complete code snippet

```
var currentTotal : Int = 0
var currentPlayer : Int = 1
var numberOfPlayers : Int = 6

@IBOutlet var CurrentPlayerTotal: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var CurrentPlayerNme: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Player1: UIImageView!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    UIImageView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        var player = self.Player1.frame
        player = CGRect(x: 16, y: 178, width: 250, height: 350)

        self.Player1.frame = player

        }, completion: { finished in
            println("done")
    })
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

// SUBTRACT
@IBAction func Sub1(sender: AnyObject) {
    currentTotal -= 1
    CurrentPlayerTotal.text = "\(currentTotal )"
}
```

The app begins the image moves to the correct spot. When I click on the button bound to the Sub1 func the image pops back to the original spot.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the answer. That provided me the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try first option if it works then okay, otherwise try the second one, it will work definitely.

1. `self.player1.layoutIfNeeded()`
   `self.player1 setNeedsDisplay()`
2. Make outlet of the NSLayoutConstraint for  uiimageview and plus/minus it as per your need rather chaging frame of the uimageview.

Comment: Do I place option #1 after the animation? Option #2 I don't understand.

Comment: option#1 you can use within or after animation block option#2 create a left constraint for uiimageview and then create outlet of this constraint, hope u get my point.

Comment: did it solve your problem?

Comment: No, not yet, I would like to use animation if possible.

Comment: Added more code above in question.

Comment: dont use this technique, create iboutlet of left/right nslayoutcontraint for uiimageview and set its constant as per ur need.